# NSArray writeFileToPath failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, plist, nsfilemanager

I'm having trouble tracking down the problem with writing an array of `NSDictionary` objects to a file.

Each key in the `NSDictionary` objects are `NSString`s, as are the values. So the array should be writable to a plist as the documentation states is necessary. Anyway, here's my code:

```
BOOL success = [representations writeToFile:[self filePathForCacheWithCacheID:cacheID] atomically:YES];
//success is NO
```

the filePath method looks like this:

```
+ (NSString *)filePathForCacheWithCacheID:(NSString *)cacheID
{
    NSURL *cachesDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [[cachesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:cacheID] absoluteString];
}
```

and the cacheID is the string "objects". At run time, the `filePathForCacheWithCacheID:` method returns a string like:

```
file:///Users/MyName/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applic‌​ations/3A57A7B3-A522-4DCC-819B-DC8DEEDCD041/Library/Caches/objects
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: What's the file path that you're writing to? I mean, what value, at run time, is returned by your `filePathForCacheWithCacheID:` method?

Comment: Looks like this for the sim: file:///Users/MyName/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/3A57A7B3-A522-4DCC-819B-DC8DEEDCD041/Library/Caches/objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is attempting to write a file to a string that represents a file URL and not a file system path. If you wish to use the return value of that method where path strings are expected, you should substitute the `absoluteString` call with `path`:

```
+ (NSString *)filePathForCacheWithCacheID:(NSString *)cacheID
{
    NSURL *cachesDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [[cachesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:cacheID] path];
}
```

Alternatively, have the `filePathForCacheWithCacheID:` method return an `NSURL` and then use the `writeToURL:atomically:` method.

```
+ (NSURL *)fileURLForCacheWithCacheID:(NSString *)cacheID
{
    NSURL *cachesDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [cachesDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:cacheID];
}
...
BOOL success = [representations writeToURL:[self fileURLForCacheWithCacheID:cacheID] atomically:YES];
```